# Change blog segment of URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

I'm doing a site redesign, and some of the URLs might be changing in a small way.  For example, instead of having blog posts in the future we may have 'stories'.

Each blog post would need to be located at site.org/story/storyname instead of the old URL, which was site.org/blog/storyname

How would I replace 'blog' with 'story' in these URLs?  Can I do it through permalinks?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the following to the "Custom Structure" option under "Common Settings" in Permalinks.

```
/story/%postname%/
```